# what is the issue in this multi threaded code

Tags: java, multithreading

This program runs to infinite loop:

```
public class NewClass {

    static void execute(String[] tasks) {
        PCTest test = new PCTest(tasks);
        new Thread(test.producer, "Prod").start();        
        new Thread(test.consumer, "Con").start();

    }
    private static class PCTest {

        private String currentTask;
        final String[] producerTasks;
        final Prod producer;
        final Consmr consumer;

        public PCTest(String[] producerTasks) {
            this.producerTasks = producerTasks;
            producer = new Prod();
            consumer = new Consmr();
        }

        private class Prod implements Runnable {

            Prod() {
            }

            public synchronized void run() {
                int i = 0;
                while (i < producerTasks.length) {
                    if (currentTask == null) {
                        currentTask = producerTasks[i++];
                        this.notify();
                    }
                    try {
                        this.wait();
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        //do Nothing
                    }

                }
            }
        }

        private class Consmr implements Runnable {

            Consmr() {
            }

            public synchronized void run() {
                int i = 0;
                while (i < producerTasks.length) {
                    if (currentTask != null) {
                        System.out.print(currentTask);
                        i++;
                        if (i < producerTasks.length) {
                            System.out.print(",");
                        }
                        currentTask = null; //*
                        this.notify();
                    }
                    try {
                        this.wait();
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        //do Nothing
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }


public static void main(String a[]){
    String ar[]={"a","b","c"};
    execute(ar);
}
}
```

Comment: We don't know. What *is* the issue?

Comment: Probably debugging will tell you more on this!

Comment: You should provide more detailed information about what you try to accomplish and what doesn't work as expected.

Answer (score 1):

From the above code, it seems your threads are in `inifinite wait` state. 
Because the wait() and notify() are not properly done.

Your Producer thread will set the `currentTask` and goes to wait by calling `this.wait()`. Here the `this` is instance of `Prod` class. Your consumer actually does a `this.notify()` but here `this` is an instance of `Consmr` class and your consumer also goes to an `inifinite wait` state.

Simply you are not `notifying` the instance which the other thread is `waiting` on

Hope its clear now.

Answer (score 0):

It will stop infinite looping if you change both calls from

```
this.wait()
```

to

```
this.wait(50)
```

That's pretty much a hack though.